# How can I import a CSV file to custom entity created using ECK module?

Tags: entities, importing-exporting

I have created a custom entity type using ECK module. I want to import a csv file with data to my custom entity. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Content imports are often done with Feeds or Migrate modules.